# sort elements in array that are greater than n in ascending order and remaining in descending in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I need to sort an array in C in both ascending and descending order.

Values greater than n need to be first and ascending and any values less than n will be at the end and in descending order. There will be an unknown number of inputs and the code below does not reflect the actual input and only serves as an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

int n = 4;
int arr[] = {5, 6, 2, 8, 3}
```

the resulting output would be 5,6,8,3,2

My solution:

```
if (arr[0] >n){
  for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
     for (j = 0; i < arrSize; j++){
     if ( arr[j] < arr[i] && arr[i] < n){
       int temp = arr[i];
       arr[i] = arr[j];
       arr[j] = temp;
     }
```

This part works fine for the first part (array elements > n) I'm having trouble with the latter part. Continuing from the previous code my solution:

```
     else if(arr[i] < n){
      int temp2 = arr[n-1];
      arr[n-1] = arr[i];
      arr[i] = temp2;
     }
```

unfortunately this only works for elements under n if they are placed in input consecutively, otherwise the sorting fails.

Any help or reference to a topic I can read on this sorting  is greatly appreciated. Apologies if this has been asked I didn't find anything similar in the stackoverflow search

Comment: Break the problem apart: **1.** Write a function that compares two elements (this is the key part here). **2.** Use any sorting algorithm (for instance the predefined `qsort`) to sort the array using your custom comparator (instead of `<`).

Comment: Is that problem online somewhere?

Comment: *"Values **greater than** n need to be first and ascending and any values **less than** n will be at the end and in descending order."* Where should any value **equal to** n go?

Comment: The problem isn't online as far I know

Comment: equal to n should prompt the user to select another input, it's in my actual code but I felt it was unnecessary to add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem in 3 steps:

- first partition the array into elements larger than `n` and elements smaller or equal to `n`.
- then sort the first half in ascending order
- and sort the second half in descending order

```c
void swap(int *array, int i, int j) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

void split_sort(int *array, int size, int n) {
    int i, j, middle;

    /* partition the array using n as a pivot value */
    for (i = 0, j = size; i < j;) {
        while (i < j && array[i] > n)
            i++;
        while (j > i && array[j - 1] <= n)
            j--;
        if (i >= j)
            break;
        swap(array, i++, --j);
    }
    middle = i;
    /* sort the left half in ascending order with a simplistic algorithm */
    for (i = 1; i < middle; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[i]) {
                swap(array, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    /* sort the right half in descending order with a simplistic algorithm */
    for (i = middle + 1; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = middle; j < i; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[i]) {
                swap(array, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you your comment made me think of the problem a different way I'll try executing my own code thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard `qsort()` function along with an appropriate comparison function.  Because you need `N` as well, it has to be a global variable.  One such comparator (with test harness) follows — but note the simpler comparator in the third program (there's always room for improvement):

```
/*
** Sort values greater than N first in ascending order, and values less
** than N last in descending order, with values equal to N in the middle.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int N;

static int comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    int a = *(int *)v1;
    int b = *(int *)v2;

    if (a < N && b < N)
        return (a < b) - (a > b);   /* Descending */
    else if (a > N && b > N)
        return (a > b) - (a < b);   /* Ascending */
    else if (a > N && b < N)
        return -1;
    else if (a < N && b > N)
        return +1;
    else if (a == N && b > N)
        return +1;
    else if (b == N && a < N)
        return +1;
    else if (a == N && b < N)
        return -1;
    else if (b == N && a > N)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, size_t n, int *data)
{
    printf("%s (%zu):\n", tag, n);
    const char *pad = "";
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && i % 10 == 0)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            pad = "";
        }
        printf("%s%3d", pad, data[i]);
        pad = ",";
    }
    if (i % 10 != 0)
        putchar('\n');
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    // random -n 100 0 99 | commalist -B 8 -n 10 -W 2
    static int data[] =
    {
        22, 90, 87, 54, 81, 72, 68, 44, 82, 56,
        45, 66, 97, 69, 84,  7, 47, 27, 77, 11,
        99, 57, 95, 61, 90, 10, 98, 17, 29, 26,
         5, 39,  8, 61, 38, 90, 92, 85, 19, 39,
        76, 34, 97,  7, 23, 19, 27, 71,  8, 59,
        64, 25, 78, 28,  6, 65, 32, 47, 96,  3,
        55,  9, 75, 59,  5, 71, 83,  0, 95,  2,
        38, 61, 96, 94, 75, 40, 87, 75, 58, 49,
         4, 48, 58,  8, 99, 60, 91, 91, 46, 27,
        90, 85, 53, 60, 85, 46, 51, 33, 71, 92,
        13, 14, 60,  3, 94, 38,  2, 62, 33, 27,
        69, 33, 36, 66, 40, 63, 53, 34, 11,  4,
        56, 66, 86,  5, 95, 84, 69, 49, 49, 39,
        48, 91, 22, 35, 50, 64, 94, 35, 44, 97,
        70, 14, 28, 36, 68, 52, 69,  2, 54, 80,
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    N = 56;
    dump_array("Before", NUM_DATA, data);
    qsort(data, NUM_DATA, sizeof(data[0]), comparator);
    dump_array("After", NUM_DATA, data);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before (150):
 22, 90, 87, 54, 81, 72, 68, 44, 82, 56
 45, 66, 97, 69, 84,  7, 47, 27, 77, 11
 99, 57, 95, 61, 90, 10, 98, 17, 29, 26
  5, 39,  8, 61, 38, 90, 92, 85, 19, 39
 76, 34, 97,  7, 23, 19, 27, 71,  8, 59
 64, 25, 78, 28,  6, 65, 32, 47, 96,  3
 55,  9, 75, 59,  5, 71, 83,  0, 95,  2
 38, 61, 96, 94, 75, 40, 87, 75, 58, 49
  4, 48, 58,  8, 99, 60, 91, 91, 46, 27
 90, 85, 53, 60, 85, 46, 51, 33, 71, 92
 13, 14, 60,  3, 94, 38,  2, 62, 33, 27
 69, 33, 36, 66, 40, 63, 53, 34, 11,  4
 56, 66, 86,  5, 95, 84, 69, 49, 49, 39
 48, 91, 22, 35, 50, 64, 94, 35, 44, 97
 70, 14, 28, 36, 68, 52, 69,  2, 54, 80
After (150):
 57, 58, 58, 59, 59, 60, 60, 60, 61, 61
 61, 62, 63, 64, 64, 65, 66, 66, 66, 68
 68, 69, 69, 69, 69, 70, 71, 71, 71, 72
 75, 75, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 83
 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 86, 87, 87, 90, 90
 90, 90, 91, 91, 91, 92, 92, 94, 94, 94
 95, 95, 95, 96, 96, 97, 97, 97, 98, 99
 99, 56, 56, 55, 54, 54, 53, 53, 52, 51
 50, 49, 49, 49, 48, 48, 47, 47, 46, 46
 45, 44, 44, 40, 40, 39, 39, 39, 38, 38
 38, 36, 36, 35, 35, 34, 34, 33, 33, 33
 32, 29, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 26, 25
 23, 22, 22, 19, 19, 17, 14, 14, 13, 11
 11, 10,  9,  8,  8,  8,  7,  7,  6,  5
  5,  5,  4,  4,  3,  3,  2,  2,  2,  0
```

On Linux and Mac systems, there is also a `qsort_r()` which allows you to pass `N` as a value to the comparator function — but unfortunately, the signatures on the two systems are different:

MacOS (BSD):

```
 void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width, void *thunk,
              int (*compar)(void *, const void *, const void *));
```

Linux:

```
void qsort_r(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
             int (*compar)(const void *, const void *, void *), void *arg);
```

The comparison function is given an extra argument, and a pointer is passed to the `qsort()` that is relayed to the comparator.  However, the calling sequences are different.  Here is code using the MacOS variant — the changes for the Linux variant are simple.

```
/*
** Sort values greater than N first in ascending order, and values less
** than N last in descending order, with values equal to N in the middle.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int comparator(void *v0, const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    int N = *(int *)v0;
    int a = *(int *)v1;
    int b = *(int *)v2;

    if (a < N && b < N)
        return (a < b) - (a > b);   /* Descending */
    else if (a > N && b > N)
        return (a > b) - (a < b);   /* Ascending */
    else if (a > N && b < N)
        return -1;
    else if (a < N && b > N)
        return +1;
    else if (a == N && b > N)
        return +1;
    else if (b == N && a < N)
        return +1;
    else if (a == N && b < N)
        return -1;
    else if (b == N && a > N)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, size_t n, int *data)
{
    printf("%s (%zu):\n", tag, n);
    const char *pad = "";
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && i % 10 == 0)
        {
            putchar('\n');
            pad = "";
        }
        printf("%s%3d", pad, data[i]);
        pad = ",";
    }
    if (i % 10 != 0)
        putchar('\n');
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int N = 56;
    // random -n 100 0 99 | commalist -B 8 -n 10 -W 2
    static int data[] =
    {
        22, 90, 87, 54, 81, 72, 68, 44, 82, 56,
        45, 66, 97, 69, 84,  7, 47, 27, 77, 11,
        99, 57, 95, 61, 90, 10, 98, 17, 29, 26,
         5, 39,  8, 61, 38, 90, 92, 85, 19, 39,
        76, 34, 97,  7, 23, 19, 27, 71,  8, 59,
        64, 25, 78, 28,  6, 65, 32, 47, 96,  3,
        55,  9, 75, 59,  5, 71, 83,  0, 95,  2,
        38, 61, 96, 94, 75, 40, 87, 75, 58, 49,
         4, 48, 58,  8, 99, 60, 91, 91, 46, 27,
        90, 85, 53, 60, 85, 46, 51, 33, 71, 92,
        13, 14, 60,  3, 94, 38,  2, 62, 33, 27,
        69, 33, 36, 66, 40, 63, 53, 34, 11,  4,
        56, 66, 86,  5, 95, 84, 69, 49, 49, 39,
        48, 91, 22, 35, 50, 64, 94, 35, 44, 97,
        70, 14, 28, 36, 68, 52, 69,  2, 54, 80,
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    dump_array("Before", NUM_DATA, data);
    qsort_r(data, NUM_DATA, sizeof(data[0]), &N, comparator);
    dump_array("After", NUM_DATA, data);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the same because the input data is the same.

As hinted by [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662914/sort-elements-in-array-that-are-greater-than-n-in-ascending-order-and-remaining/63664132?noredirect=1#comment112581868_63664132), it is possible to simplify the conditions by noting that you have an ascending sequence N+1 .. MAX followed by a descending sequence N .. MIN.  Here's an adaptation of the 'plain `qsort()`' code that generates arrays with a random number of entries in the value range 0 .. 99, and that sets the breakpoint, `N`, to a random value 20 .. 79.  It sorts the original fixed data, and then 10 sets of random data.  It also includes a function `check_order()` which verifies that the data is sorted.  It spotted problems in the results when the comparator function was broken.

```
/* SO 6366-2914 */
/*
** Sort values greater than N first in ascending order, and values less
** than or equal to N last in descending order.
*/

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define RETURN(v) \
    do { \
        if (print_return) \
            printf("%2d: %2d <=> %2d --> %+d\n", __LINE__, a, b, (v)); \
        return(v); \
    } while (0)

static int print_return = 0;
static int N;

static int comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    int a = *(int *)v1;
    int b = *(int *)v2;

    if (a <= N && b <= N)
        return((a < b) - (a > b));   /* Descending */
    else if (a > N && b > N)
        return((a > b) - (a < b));   /* Ascending */
    else if (a > N)
    {
        assert(b <= N);
        RETURN(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(a <= N && b > N);
        RETURN(+1);
    }
}

static void dump_array(const char *tag, size_t n, const int *data)
{
    printf("%s (%zu) N = %2d:", tag, n, N);
    const char *pad = "";
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 10 == 0)
            pad = "\n";
        printf("%s%3d", pad, data[i]);
        pad = ",";
    }
    putchar('\n');
    putchar('\n');
}

static void check_order(size_t n, const int *data, int breakpoint)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n && data[i] > breakpoint; i++)
    {
        if (data[i-1] > data[i])
            fprintf(stderr, "FAIL: A[%zu] = %2d out of ascending sequence with A[%zu] = %2d\n",
                    i-1, data[i-1], i, data[i]);
    }
    for ( ; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (data[i-1] < data[i])
            fprintf(stderr, "FAIL: A[%zu] = %2d out of descending sequence with A[%zu] = %2d\n",
                    i-1, data[i-1], i, data[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    // random -n 100 0 99 | commalist -B 8 -n 10 -W 2
    static int data[] =
    {
        22, 90, 87, 54, 81, 72, 68, 44, 82, 56,
        45, 66, 97, 69, 84,  7, 47, 27, 77, 11,
        99, 57, 95, 61, 90, 10, 98, 17, 29, 26,
         5, 39,  8, 61, 38, 90, 92, 85, 19, 39,
        76, 34, 97,  7, 23, 19, 27, 71,  8, 59,
        64, 25, 78, 28,  6, 65, 32, 47, 96,  3,
        55,  9, 75, 59,  5, 71, 83,  0, 95,  2,
        38, 61, 96, 94, 75, 40, 87, 75, 58, 49,
         4, 48, 58,  8, 99, 60, 91, 91, 46, 27,
        90, 85, 53, 60, 85, 46, 51, 33, 71, 92,
        13, 14, 60,  3, 94, 38,  2, 62, 33, 27,
        69, 33, 36, 66, 40, 63, 53, 34, 11,  4,
        56, 66, 86,  5, 95, 84, 69, 49, 49, 39,
        48, 91, 22, 35, 50, 64, 94, 35, 44, 97,
        70, 14, 28, 36, 68, 52, 69,  2, 54, 80,
    };
    enum { NUM_DATA = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]) };

    N = 56;
    dump_array("Before", NUM_DATA, data);
    qsort(data, NUM_DATA, sizeof(data[0]), comparator);
    dump_array("After", NUM_DATA, data);
    check_order(NUM_DATA, data, N);

    srand(time(0));

    for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        size_t n = rand() % 120 + 30;
        N = rand() % 60 + 20;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            data[i] = rand() % 100;
        dump_array("Before", n, data);
        qsort(data, n, sizeof(data[0]), comparator);
        dump_array("After", n, data);
        check_order(n, data, N);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code has a crude debugging facility with the `RETURN` macro.  It prints diagnostic information when the `print_return` variable is set to `1`.  All the return statements in the comparator could use the macro.  It was useful when checking which comparisons in the comparator function could be omitted.

The code could be made more thorough.  It could check for conservation properties (each value in the output appears in the input; each value in the input appears in the output).  It could use a better random number generator than the `srand()`/`rand()` combination.  It could read numbers from standard input (or a named file), or be controlled by command-line arguments — so that the seed could be specified on the command line, or printed for reproducibility.  All such modifications are left as exercises for the reader.

Comment: Interesting approach! It seems possible to simplify the comparison function by using `a <= N` an `b <= N` instead of `a < N`  and `b < N` and remove the extra tests.

Comment: @chqrlie — you're right.  I've included a third version of the program that has a simpler comparator and that has code to check that the data is sorted correctly.  Instead of 8 lines of conditions, there are just 3 in the revised code — much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

1. Use the quick-sort pivot technique for a single iteration (may require a custom implementation) to split the given into two arrays (one requiring ascending and the other descending). This pivot is the same as the the one in your problem-statement.
2. Sort the left half ascending and right half descending using quicksort or equivalent.
3. Sorting algorithms have 'stable' (the order of elements are retained) and 'inplace' (do not use additional memory/RAM) aspects/behaviours. You have not indicated this in your question so am assuming that 'stable' behaviour is not required. If its required you may have to modify the first step and use a merge sort kind of technique (one iteration) for the partitioning and subsequently use merge sort to sort the arrays in ascending and descending order.
4. Note - For sorting in descending order, you can simply sort the array in ascending order first and then reverse it!
5. Update #1: As noted by [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) in the comments, need to be careful while reversing so as to retain the 'stable' behaviour of elements (specifically, do not apply reverse for equal elements) !

Comment: *you can simply sort the array in ascending order first and then reverse it!* Note that this method is not stable even if the sorting method used for the ascending order is.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the quick sort pivot so I'll read into that first thank you

Comment: @chqrlie - Guess you are right. We'd need to retain the order for equal elements. Thanks!

Comment: @chqrlie - In any case looks more like an assignment for the OP so some auto-grading test case may catch it and advice accordingly. No real harm done I hope! Will edit my answer in any case.

Comment: @RavindraHV: no problem, stability seems beyond the scope of the question, I just wanted to underscore the potential problem with reversing a sorted array.