# How do I use qsort() to sort the array elements of each struct instance in a struct array?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, qsort, ansi-c

My objective is to use qsort() to order the 70 element pairs of each of the 9 struct instances using the "rank" column.
I created a compare function although I know this will sort the set of 9 and not the elements within each instance. Do I need to apply qsort() on each of the 9 structs separetely?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    float rank[70];
    char order[70];
    }nq;

int compF(const void * a, const void * b) {
    
    nq *orderA = (nq *)a;
    nq *orderB = (nq *)b;
    
    return(orderB->rank - orderA->rank);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    nq arr[9];

    // code populates the 70 values of each array within the 9 element struc array 
    
    qsort(arr,9,sizeof(nq),compF);  // this is wrong
    
    return 0;       
}
```

Comment: `return(orderB->rank - orderA->rank);` compares the *addresses* of the arrays.  You're sorting by address.  That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: I don't think you can use `qsort()` to sort multiple arrays in parallel like your  `rank` and `order` elements.  To swap the elements being sorted, `qsort()` works on contiguous memory, but your independent array members don't meet that criterion.  You could sort an array of structures `struct { float rank; char order; }`, but not what you've got.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting multiple arrays in the struct based on the ascending order of one array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039544/sorting-multiple-arrays-in-the-struct-based-on-the-ascending-order-of-one-array)

Comment: 1) Your current code has undefined behavior in the compare function.  Pointer arithmetic   on pointers to different objects isn't allowed. 2) Yes, if you want to sort the arrays inside the structs, you need to call `qsort` for each array, i.e. 9 * 2 = 18 calls. 3) If the purpose is to apply the same sorting to `rank` and `order` then `qsort` is the wrong tool. `qsort` can sort a **single array**. It can't apply the same sorting to multiple arrays. The work-around is to define an additional struct with one `rank` value and one `order` value and then make an array[70] of that struct.

Comment: One option is to create an extra array, `size_t order[N];` initialized so that `order[i] == i`.  You then use `arr[order[i]]` to access the element in the `i`th position.  And by sorting the `order` array, accessing the real array in the comparison function.  You really need to use one of the `qsort_r()` functions, but it is not standardized by POSIX. There are two conflicting definitions in the wild — one version on BSD-derived systems and the other on systems using GlibC, the GNU C Library — Linux and friends.  (This conflict is probably why POSIX hasn't standardized it.)

Comment: See [SO 4715-1134](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47151134/15168) and [SO 6366-2914](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63662914/15168) for discussions of `qsort_r()`.  One of the answers to the earlier question also demonstrates the use of an extra array as I suggested in my prior comment.